# How to display a list of timezones for vendors to choose from when he lists an event and other visitors are able to see the time in their local time?

Tags: mysql, node.js, django, timestamp-with-timezone, django-timezone

We have a web app(**Django** based **backend** and **Node/ReactJs based front-end**, **MySQL** based **DB**), and a Flutter based mobile app. We are creating a system where a vendor can create a meeting invite and **list the time (and timezone) at which the meeting starts**.
Visitors for that meeting should be able to see the time (and timezone) in their local time.

We will be having visitors' location and timezone ID based on their IP.

I can't figure out **how to display** the list of timezones(preferably in the GMT+xxxx format ) **in the front-end** for the vendor to choose when he creates an invite and in **what format it should be sent to the backend** and stored so that I am **able to convert it and display it to the visiting user based on his location's timezone**?

I would be really grateful if someone here can point me to the right question if it has been asked already or some document from which I can refer to for the implementation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pytz for creating a list of timezones.

There's documentation in Django stating how to select current timezone and creating a list of timezones [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone)

---

**Create a list of timezone select option**

```py
# views.py
import pytz

def your_views(request):
    # code
    return render(request, 'your_template.html', {'timezones': pytz.common_timezones})
```

In your_template.html file

```html
<select name="timezone">
    {% for tz in timezones %}
    <option value="{{ tz }}">{{ tz }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: Is there a way to list all the timezones in this?
How will I display it in frontend and what should be the format of response sent from the frontend?

Comment: @HARSHITBAJPAI yes there is. `import pytz` and pass `{'timezones': pytz.common_timezones}` in context. You can loop through this to create a select option list for timezone selection. In template.html provided in docs you can see how the context has been implemented to create a select option list

Answer (score 0):

Normal people don't like GMT+X. Second, basing a timezone on IP is irritating for people using VPNs, especially since the browser stores a timezone based on computer settings. Granted, it takes a request to be sent via javascript, so the first page won't know what the timezone is. See [Intl.DateTimeFormat.resolvedOptions().timeZone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/resolvedOptions#Browser_compatibility#Description).

To generate choices that correspond with that list, use `pytz.common_timezones`:

```py
import pytz

class YourModel(models.Model):
    TZ_CHOICES = ((v, v) for v in pytz.common_timezones)
    time_zone = models.CharField(choices=TZ_CHOICES)
```